# How do I deploy Searchkick in production after setting up my own Elasticsearch server on EC2?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, amazon-ec2, searchkick

Under the Deployment section on [Searchkick's README file](https://github.com/ankane/searchkick), it has instructions for deploying searchkick when using Heroku or Amazon Elasticsearch.

But since I'm rolling my own Elasticsearch server on EC2, how do I deploy it?

Comment: Exactly as described under the [Other section](https://github.com/ankane/searchkick#other) ;-)

Comment: Should I just copy paste it? I'm confused on username, password, api.searchbox.io

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply need to use your own EC2 URL on which you have installed your ES cluster and configure it in the `config/initializers/elasticsearch.rb` file like this:

```
ENV["ELASTICSEARCH_URL"] = "http://your.es-server.com:9200"
```

If you decide to set up BASIC auth then you can add your username/password to the URL as well

```
ENV["ELASTICSEARCH_URL"] = "http://your-username:your-password@your.es-server.com:9200"
```

Comment: Oh I see. By the way, I haven't set up my own Elasticsearch server on EC2 yet, I just asked in advanced. [This is the guide](https://www.elastic.co/blog/running-elasticsearch-on-aws) I will be using for setting up my own Elasticsearch Server on EC2. Is that the correct guide?

Comment: This guide uses Elasticsearch 2.3.3. Can I just change it to the current Elasticsearch version? I mean, does EC2 accept any Elasticsearch version?

Comment: EC2 is just an environment where you can install anything so by all means, use the latest ES version if you're just starting from scratch.